# PyCharm changes system keyboard layout

Tags: pycharm

I'm using **PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3 Build #PC-163.8233.8** on `Windows 10`, and it erratically changes the system-wide keyboard layout from German to English. I want it to stop doing that but haven't found any setting related to this.

My problem seems to be related but different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124444/pycharm-language-for-keyboard-shortcuts-change), where the internal `PyCharm` setting is set to German for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out this is related to Windows 10, not PyCharm. In PyCharm, one often uses Alt + Shift + E to execute code. In Windows 10, Alt + Shift (sometimes Ctrl + Shift) also switches keyboard layouts, so this explains the behavior. Following [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/976947/keyboard-language-keeps-changing-in-windows-10), one can change this at Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Advanced settings under "Change language bar hot keys".

Comment: Thank you for saving me from going crazy almost five years later.

Answer (score 1):

Note the option at the bottom of the screen in `Settings>Keymap`to enable `Use national layouts for shortcuts`. This helped me with my US qwerty keyboard. I use EN US keyboard layout by default but Pycharm confused it with the other layout I have on my system until I enabled that option.
[image: enable national layouts]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the problem of PyCharm.

I have 2 PC with Windows 7 and Windows 10 with French (default) and Russian keyboard layout on both of them. After installing of PyCharm (with 2 weeks interval) an English keyboard layout is appeared on both PCs. And the most surrising is the fact that the Control Panel (Regional Settings -> Keyboard layouts) shows only French and Russian layouts. But if you click on the system tray's icon, you can see 3 of them.

I vaguely remember the question that PyCharm asks me after install, it was something about "non standard keyboard layout". I remember that I allowed PyCharg to manage this fact, but I didn't realize that it will add me a "phantom" layout that I can not remove.

Update: unistalling / reinstalling PyCharm change nothing. But a simple Windows restart removes English keyboard. Till the first launch of my prject from PyCharmm after which a third (English) keyboard layout appears. And I keep this layout even after closing of PyCharm.

Just in case: my python project have nothing to do with keyboard layouts. It's a simple board game simulator, using only mouse to interacte with the player.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is related to having instaled different Keyboards in the Regional and Language Options.

pyCharm seems to be taking the English configuration instead of the one that is configured as default. (in my case LatinAmerican).

If you delete the other languages and reopen pyCharm it works ok.