# JetBrains' IDEs keep changing keyboard layout

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, keyboard-layout

Both my JetBrains' IDEs (PyCharm and IntelliJ) keep automatically changing keyboard layout. I realize this question is a duplicate (kind of) of e.g. this one [PyCharm changes system keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649015/pycharm-changes-system-keyboard-layout), but something else is happening to me. Difference being that it happens automatically.

When I switch (<kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd>, or mouse click on taskbar) to the IDE, keyboard language immediately changes. From what I understand, it changes to system default.

Now here's where it gets tricky. I use Czech and English keyboard for writing Czech stuff and programming, respectively. But because I really hated that the default system Czech keyboard is QWERTZ, whereas English one is QWERTY, I deleted the QWERTZ one and added QWERTY one instead.

But IDE somehow still changes my keyboard to the Czech QWERTZ one. **How can I disable this?** Or at least force IntelliJ and PyCharm to not use the one default keyboard which I deleted, but one of those I have activated. (It's really annoying when Y/Z change keys.)

Additional info:

- It switches only when I am currently using English keyboard (I see ENG on Windows taskbar). Seems like IDE detects I am not using system default language and changes it - unfortunately to the wrong (deleted) keyboard layout of said language.
- Language visible on the taskbar doesn't actually change, but keyboard layout is Czech QWERTZ. I am guessing it doesn't change, because it's not present (since I deleted it) in the list of available languages/keyboard layouts.
- When I use Win shortcut for changing languages (<kbd>Alt + Shift</kbd>) after this happened, it keeps switching between English and Czech QWERTZ (while there is ENG on the taskbar all the time). I have to manually change to Czech QWERTY to fix it (only to have it happen again soon enough).
- Keyboard layout is changed for whole system (all other programs). It's not like IDE would change it only for itself.

I am using:

- Windows 10 Pro, build 16299.248
- PyCharm Professional 2017.3.1, build #PY-173.3942.36
- IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.2.6, build #IJ-172.4574.11

Comment: Please file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) attached after IDE restart.

Comment: @Andrey ok, thanks, I'll try

Comment: @awa993 Did you find anything? Or if you filed an issue, would you please put the link here?

Comment: @ShayanToqraee No, not yet. I have to work on my master's thesis, so I can't be bothered right now with this. I will probably fill an issue eventually. When/if that happens, I will put the link here.

Comment: I am also experiencing this currently. Makes it really difficult to multitask while using PHPStorm on Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, I'm even getting this on Linux in '22!   Build #IU-222.3739.54, built on August 16, 2022